# How can I regex a group of characters in javascript? (\/)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string and I want to regex out only certain characters that are "together." How can I go by doing this? The characters I'm trying to check for are the backslash next to the forward slash.

http://jsfiddle.net/H4e7p/2/

Example:

Here is a string I'm regexing against:

```
Hello world! How \ar/e you? \/\/\/\/\/\/\\\\\\\\/\/
```

This is what it **should** look like:

```
Hello world! How \ar/e you? ******\\\\\\\**
```

This is what it **actually** looks like:

```
Hello world! How *ar*e you? ***********************
```

And here is the regex I'm currently using:

```
/[\\/]/g
```

What does the regex have to look like in order to accomplish checking for a group of characters? (\/)

Comment: Why not simply use `/\\\//g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used wrong regular syntax: [`[xyz]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-character-set) is

> A character set. Matches any one of the enclosed characters.

Try the following regex instead: `/\\\//g`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/H4e7p/3/

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `/[\\\/]/g` is either \ or /

But you want   `/(\\\/)/g`

**edit** corrected escaping of /